# How can i replace the rows and columns of an confusion matrix?

Tags: python, confusion-matrix

I have a code that tries to classify the ship class. I have finished and taken the confusion matrix. But now I want to arrange the matrix, so everybody will see the same class in serial not in alphabetical. i can't load the picture of confusion matrix because of lack of reputation.

I want to replacement the labels and the values which are appointed to their labels from this: `Ada, Burak, Doğan, Gabya, Kılıç, Meko, Rüzgar, Yıldız, YTKB` as rows and columns
to this: `Gabya, Meko, Ada, Burak, YTKB, Kılıç, Doğan, Rüzgar, Yıldız` as rows and labels.

```
def plot_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, classes,
                      normalize=True,
                      title=None,
                      cmap=plt.cm.Reds):

    cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, out)
    cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    im = ax.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    ax.figure.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
    ax.set(xticks=np.arange(cm.shape[1]),
           yticks=np.arange(cm.shape[0]),
           xticklabels=classes, 
           yticklabels=classes,
           title=title)

    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right",
         rotation_mode="anchor")

plot_confusion_matrix(y_test, out, classes=classes, normalize=True)

plt.imshow()
```

Comment: Please provide some code so we can see how you are generating the figures. Is it a function you are using?

Comment: ok i will write the confusion_matrix code above.